# How to group images on multi galleries with FANCYBOX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

How to group galleries to show only photos from same group?

Right now getting images via data-fancybox the problem is that i have dynamical id of group.

fancybox version: v3.5.7

```html
<a class="fancyfunc" data-fancybox-group="group_<?=$r['reference_id'];?>"  href="<?=$img['image'];?>"  data-fancybox="images">
   <img class="none" src="<?=$img['image'];?>" />
</a>
```

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({

    margin : [44,0,22,0],
    thumbs : {
        autoStart : true,
        axis      : 'x'
    }
})
```

Comment: This `data-fancybox-group="group_<?=$r['reference_id'];?>"` should work already, as long as you correctly pass the same reference_id to same group links. Please notice your `class` attribute is missing a doublequote

Comment: But not work  this $('[data-fancybox="images"]')  need to be target to data-fancybox-group

Comment: updated the description  my mistake  when in post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See docs - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage -

> [..] use the same attribute `data-fancybox` value for each of them to create
>   a gallery.

So, replace

`data-fancybox-group="group_<?=$r['reference_id'];?>"`

with

`data-fancybox="group_<?=$r['reference_id'];?>"`

Comment: and what about this static call ? $('[data-fancybox="group_"]').fancybox({})  i get now only one image in payload

Comment: You apply click event (that starts fancybox) to elements that matches your selector (e.g., what `$('[data-fancybox="group_"]')` returns); groups are created based on value of `data-fancybox` attribute.